# SwiftUI: How to call a function to populate a LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on some code in SwiftUI (learning as I go) where I'm constructing a vertical grid of items (This is heavily simplified for the purposes of this question):

```swift
let col1 = GridItem(alignment: .leading)
let col2 = GridItem(alignment: .trailing)

LazyVGrid(columns: [col1, col2]) {
    Text("C1")
    Text("C1")
    Text("C2")
    Text("C2")
}
```

So I get something like this:

```
+----+----+
| C1 | C1 |
+----+----+
| C2 | C2 |
+----+----+
```

Now in my code I'm doing some other stuff so I'd like to extract a function so my code looks something like this:

```swift
let col1 = GridItem(alignment: .leading)
let col2 = GridItem(alignment: .trailing)

LazyVGrid(columns: [col1, col2]) {
    row("C1")
    row("C2")
}

func row(text: String) -> ???? {
    Text(text)
    Text(text)
}
```

But I'm finding it difficult to see how to do it. Does the function return an array? or is there some aspect of Swift's builders I can use here? I tried an array but `LazyVGrid`'s build didn't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Research the [`@ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) attribute. This makes the function behave like the closure you're passing to `LazyVGrid` and many of the SwiftUI Views.

```
@ViewBuilder
func row(text: String) -> some View {
    Text(text)
    Text(text)
}
```

Comment: Of course. Thank you.